# xDebug cannot stop on breakpoints if nested pages load (yii, phpStorm)

Tags: php, yii, phpstorm, xdebug

What i have:

1. OpenServer with PHP Version 5.4.26 enabled
2. Yii
3. xDebug 2.2.4
4. Windows 7
5. PhpStorm 7

Config for xDebug^

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="%sprogdir%/modules/php/%phpdriver%/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/xdebug/"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%H%R"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1 
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

Problem:
I put 3 breakpoints in my yii project, first i put in the index.php, second in the MainController -> actionIndex, third in the some other controller action like OtherController -> actionOther

When i try to start debug main controller xDebug stops on first and second breakpints, but when i try to open url for OtherController -> actionOther it don`t. Why this may happen?

Comment: 1) Use 2.2.5 as 2.2.4 has some issues; 2) What kind of line is that? Maybe xdebug is unable to break there. Always try to place breakpoints on simple single-line statements 3) Will it break if you place `xdebug_break();` there? 4) Other than that -- enable xdebug logging and check it.

Comment: 1) ok i will try 2.2.5 instead of 2.2.4. 
2) Its line in action with php code, like "$this->render('something');"

Comment: 3) no it is not break on xdebug_break()

Comment: If it's not breaking on programmatic breakpoint ... then disable all breakpoints and do the xdebug log. It's possible that the path mapping could be wrong/incomplete for this file or folder (you have to remember that xdebug works with final/resolved paths ONLY while IDE will take symbolic links as is). That's, of course, if that line gets executed at all.